# SOLR: how to see when document/row was last indexed?

Tags: solr

is there anyway to get a timestamp of when a document/row was last updated or indexed?
sort of like the fields created_at or updated_at for activerecord.

Comment: According to this, no, there's no way: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/anyway-to-get-Document-update-time-stamp-td501835.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ben commented, there is not a built in way to do this. The only option would be to create the following timestamp field in your schema. Then this value would always be the last time that the document/row was last indexed.

```
    <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" 
         stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

This is taken from the example [schema.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_4_1/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml?view=markup) that ships with Solr.